# Oracle - Selecting a string before a specific string

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, I have a string "TARGET CONSUMER CLAIM" and I would like to select all the string before ' CLAIM'. My output should be 'TARGET CONSUMER'. I tried regexp_substr and also substr with instr command but couldn't get the correct answer

Comment: show us your attempt explicitly, and tag the question with your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression replacement function [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) to remove the part you don't want:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, ' CLAIM.*', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) to find the location of `CLAIM` in your string, and then [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) to extract the portion of the string before that location:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('TARGET CONSUMER CLAIM', 1, INSTR('TARGET CONSUMER CLAIM', ' CLAIM') - 1) FROM dual
```

Output

```
TARGET CONSUMER
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use REGEXP_INSTR:

```
select substr('TARGET CONSUMER CLAIM',1,REGEXP_INSTR('TARGET CONSUMER CLAIM', '(\s)+CLAIM')-1) 
from dual;
```